# Missing requried props when using beforeEnter() route guard

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I am trying to fetch data from API using `beforeEnter()` route guard but I am getting an error:

`Missing required prop: "rides"`

Here's my code.

#### router.js

```
{
   path: '/',
   name: 'home',
   component: () => import('./components/main.vue'),
   props: true,
   beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
     store.dispatch('ride/fetchRides').then(rides => {
       to.params.rides = rides
       next()
     })
   }
}
```

#### actions.js

```
fetchRides({ commit, dispatch }) {
    return statistcsService.ridesForCurrentWeek()
      .then(response => {
        commit('SET_RIDES', response.data)
        return response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const notification = {
          type: 'danger',
          message: 'There was a problem fetching your rides'
        }
        dispatch('notification/add', notification, { root: true })
        throw error
      })
  }
```

#### Index.vue

```
<script>
    export default {
      props: {
        rides: {
          type: Array,
          required: true
        }
      }
    ...
  }
</script>
```

What am I missing? The prop is set in the component so am I not sure why it is crying.
I have verified that in 100% I am getting the data from API response.

Comment: You already seem to be using vuex is there any reason to pass it as props from router instead of accessing the state for `SET_RIDES` inside the component?

Comment: Yes, I want to display `NProgress` progress bar and a spinner when the data is being loaded. In order to achieve this, I need to remove the dependency between my component and VueX so that I can fetch the data on `beforeEnter()` route guard and then send the data as props to the component. Otherwise, the data will be fetched on `created()` lifecycle hook, before the progress bar and the spinner shows.

Comment: @Gowri Here's my source code if you need to see more code https://github.com/jedrekdomanski/bikeramp-front

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add `rides` property in your html code for that component? According to the error message - that's the problem.

Comment: @AndrewShmig As you can see in the component snippet, I did set the prop `rides`.

Comment: @jedi, I don't see any component with `rides` property being set. Where is your HTML-component with `:rides=...` ?

Comment: I think I get it. The component that receives the props is `main.vue` so it needs to have props `rides` defined as well. I also needed to pass `:rides="rides"` to `<Ride/>` component that I render in `main.vue`. I did that and it worked.

Comment: @jedi, posted my comment as an answer. Glad that it did work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `rides` property in your html code for that component. According to the error message - that's the problem.

Example:

```
<component :rides="rides"></component>
```

Comment: I skipped my mind that the component that receives props from params is /components/main.vue and that I needed to set props `rides` there as well. This answer and previous comment led me to the root cause of the issue and helped me solve it. Thank you.